# CnosDB missing system table for obtaining meta information

Tags: cnosdb

Currently, CnosDB only has SQL for displaying nodes:

```
public ❯ show datanodes;
+---------+-----------+-----------+---------+-----------+---------------------+
| NODE_ID | HOST      | ATTRIBUTE | STATUS  | DISK_FREE | LAST_UPDATED_TIME   |
+---------+-----------+-----------+---------+-----------+---------------------+
| 1001    | localhost | HOT       | HEALTHY | 11.09 GB  | 2023-06-07 08:01:25 |
| 2001    | localhost | HOT       | HEALTHY | 11.09 GB  | 2023-06-07 08:01:25 |
| 3001    | localhost | HOT       | HEALTHY | 11.09 GB  | 2023-06-07 08:01:25 |
| 4001    | localhost | HOT       | HEALTHY | 11.09 GB  | 2023-06-07 08:01:26 |
+---------+-----------+-----------+---------+-----------+---------------------+
Query took 0.012 seconds.
```

I hope to add an information table for VNodes, which includes the following fields:
VNodeID, VNodeGroupID, Bucket, Database, NodeID, StartTime, EndTime.

Regarding the fields:

For the VNodeGroup field, I hope to have a separate table to record information about VNodeGroups;

For the Bucket field, I hope to have a separate table to record information about Buckets.

Regarding the Database field, currently the displayed information for "show databases" is as follows:

```
public ❯  show databases;
+-----------------+
| database_name   |
+-----------------+
| oceanic_station |
| public          |
| usage_schema    |
+-----------------+
Query took 0.008 seconds.
```

I hope to have a table that associates databases with tenants.